# I need some help passing an array and having the option to return a null array

Tags: java, methods, return

Sorry, this is my first time using this site. 
I am trying to return a null array. 
Hoping to get a few pointers.
I at first tried return null. But then changed it to set all the array values to -1. Code is listed below, I suppose. Thanks any help is greatly appreciated. I'm getting the error "This method must return a result of type   int[]" in Eclipse

```
public static int[] consecutive_Numbers(int[] integer_array)
    {
        boolean numbers_found = true;
        while (!numbers_found)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No consecutive numbers found");
            for(int a=0; a < integer_array.length; a++ )
            {
                integer_array[a] = -1;
            }
            return integer_array;
        }

        if(integer_array.length <= 0)
        {
            numbers_found = false;
        }

        else
        {
            for(int i = 5; i < integer_array.length; i++)
            {
                int counting = 1;
                do
                {
                    counting = counting + 1;
                }
                while(integer_array[i - counting] == integer_array[i + counting]);
                if(counting >= 4)
                {
                    int second_count = (counting * 2) + 1;
                    int[] int_array2 = new int[second_count];
                    int newIndex = i;
                    int m = i+counting;

                    for(int j = (second_count-1)/2; j > -1; j--)
                    {
                        int_array2[j] =  integer_array[newIndex];
                        newIndex--;
                    }
                    for(int k = second_count; k > (second_count-1)/2; k--)
                    {
                        int_array2[k] = integer_array[m];
                        m--;
                    }
                return int_array2; 
                }
            }
        for(int b=0; b < integer_array.length; b++ )
        {
            integer_array[b] = -1;
        }
        return integer_array;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `if` branch return something as well? Currently only `while` and `else` do.

Comment: Ah that's probably it. I should nest the while loop in the if statement.

Update: that took care of it. Nested the while loop inside the if statement and took the return statement that was nested in the while loop and nested in the if statement as well. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot have `null` as a value for primitives like `int, float, short` etc. Only `objects` can have `null` as a value. So what you could do is define an array of the wrapper class `Integer` instead of `int`. `Interger arr[]=new Integer[5]; arr[i]=null;` won't give you an error.